# Gtesting Type Parametrized Test Instantion and Registration in different namespaces

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using Gtest's Type Parameterized Testing Facility. Based on my code structure, I need to register and instantiate the Gtest Fixture in two separate namespaces. I get a compilation error when I try to do that. How should I place the instantiation and registration of Gtest Type Parameterized Testing Facility in two different namespaces.

File1.hh

```
namespace A
{
   TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(TypesUnderTest);

   TYPED_CASE_P(TypesUnderTest, DoesBlah)
   {
       EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
   }

   REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(TypesUnderTest, DoesBlah);
}
```

File2

```
#include "File1"

namespace
{
    INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(prefix_name, A::TypesUnderTest, ConcreteType);
}
```

I get an error message that-

```
use of undeclared identifier 'gtest_prefix_name_A'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference to anyone coming across this issue.

It is not possible to instantiate the test suite in a different namespace other than where the tests were initialized and registered.

This is because the Gtest macros use the `TestSuite` Name as is to declare a new namespace inside the registered namespace something like

```
namespace testsuite_initialization&registration
{
   namespace gtest_suite_namespace_##TestSuite##
   {
        // local variables used by gtest to find tests
   }
}
```

And variables are declared inside this namespace during registration process.

However, when this test suite is called from outside the namespace where the test suite was registered, then it is not possible to reach to this namespace because Macros are processed before namespaces get processed and thus it can't reach to the inner namespace.